# Understanding completeness relation and writing Hamiltonian in matrix form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

A three level system hamiltonian I found where it is written as:

$$\frac{H}{\hbar}= \Omega_1|e\rangle \langle g_1| + \Omega_1^* |g_1\rangle \langle e| + \Omega_2|e\rangle \langle g_2|+ \Omega_2^* |g_2\rangle \langle e|   $$

Where the $\Omega_1$,  $\Omega_2$,  are two complex coupling parameters for the normalized states $|g_1\rangle$,$|g_2\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$.

I do not understand how they write the Hamiltonian in the matrix form like this??
\begin{vmatrix}
0&0&\Omega\\
0&0&\Omega\\
\Omega&\Omega&0\\
\end{vmatrix}

For real $Ω_1 = Ω_2 = Ω$.

It would be helpful if you  disintegrate the the Hamiltonian in much simpler form so I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check how the Hamiltonian acts on the three normalized states.

Comment: Can you give me example of just one component for example $H_{11}$ matrix ?

Comment: @user193422 : Just multiply the Hamiltonian by $<g_1|$ from the left and by $|g_1>$ from the right.

Comment: Be careful, that is the form of the Hamiltonian in the base {|e>, |g_1>, |g_2>}. When you write a matrix explicitely you have always to specify in which base this is done.